# Why does a list comprehension not append in python

Tags: python, numpy

I create a list comprehension  that tries to imitate Matlab Cell of 3x3 Matrices.

```
kis= [ np.zeros(shape=(3,3)) for t in range(1, 5) ]
```

This is just like a cell in Matlab having five 3x3 zero matrices. I can access them as

```
kis[0]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I can modify them as

```
>>> kis[0][0][1]=2
>>> kis[0]
array([[ 0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> kis[0][0][1]
2.0
```

Right now there are 5 elements, say i wish to add a sixth element.

```
kis.append(np.zeros(shape=(3,3)))
```

When i try to access the sixth cell element which is supposed to be a 3x3 matrices of zeros, i have this error:

```
>>> kis[5]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    kis[5]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So how to append more 3x3 matrices into the list? Why the above method does not work? The above code is in Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> kis= [ np.zeros(shape=(3,3)) for t in range(1, 5) ]
>>> len(kis)
4
```

so last index is 3. when you:

```
>>> kis.append(np.zeros(shape=(3,3)))
>>> len(kis)
5
```

last index is 4.
so, kis[5] is out of range

Answer (score 3):

```
kis= [ np.zeros(shape=(3,3)) for t in range(1, 5) ]
#                             only 4 things ^^^^
```

If you want 5 elements, you want `range(5)`.